# Escape working directory with whitespaces in Intellij project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an Intellij project in Linux, which works perfectly fine when the path to it contains no whitespaces. But when I move it to another directory, which contains whitespaces, I can't run it anymore:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
```

I tried to escape the working directory using `""` or using just relative path `.`. I also removed and created a new Run Configuration, but it's all the same.

When I copy the project somewhere without whitespaces, it just works.

Comment: Did you right-click on the file that you moved and select "Run"?  My gut feeling tells me that IntelliJ has a configuration lurking around that is still pointed to the location of the old file.

Comment: I moved the whole project to another directory. I tried to remove run configuration and create a new one, but it still throws an exception. If I copy the project to some directory without whitespaces, it works immediately.

Comment: What OS are you on?  It'd be worth mentioning that.